# How to make a menu pop up after mouse release

Tags: c#, opengl, glut

Hi I am using C# and taoframework opengl and glut

here is my BuildMenu()

```
private static void BuildMenu()  
{  
    submenu1 = Glut.glutCreateMenu(selectMessage);  
            Glut.glutAddMenuEntry("New Game(N)", 1);  
            Glut.glutAddMenuEntry("Reset(R)", 2);  
            Glut.glutAddMenuEntry("Quit(Q)", 3);  
    Glut.glutAttachMenu(button); //**makes the menu pop up once the button is pressed.**  
}
```

How can I make it pop up after mouse release??

Answer (score 0):

Using GLUT? You can't (or only with a lot of headaches). The solution?

Don't use GLUT. GLUT started as some in-situ framework for demonstrating simple OpenGL programs. It's neither part of OpenGL nor very flexible (as you found out). And it's unmaintained.

Either use a real toolkit, there are a lot of them: Qt, GTK, wxWidgets, FLTK, Fox... Or if you're really focused on only doing OpenGL I may suggest using [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org), which is the better GLUT, but you'll have to draw the menus yourself (using OpenGL).

Comment: SDL or SFML would be better though =)